# Do DRF views use its queryset's object manager?

Tags: django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-managers, django-viewsets

If I have a custom object manager with a custom `create` function for a model:

```
class CustomManager(models.Manager):
  def get_queryset(self):
    return super().get_queryset().filter(custom=True)
  def create(self):
    kwargs["custom"] = True
    return super().create(**kwargs)

class Item(models.Model):
   customs = CustomManager()
   custom = BooleanField()
   ...
```

And I use that custom manager as the queryset for a view:

```
class ItemViewSet(views.ModelViewSet):
   queryset = Item.customs.all()
```

Will the `ItemViewSet`'s create/post function automatically apply my custom object manager's `kwargs["custom"] = True`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The creation on `ModelViewSet`s is handled by the `serializer_class` as seen on the [`CreateModelMixin`](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/mixins.py#L16-L24) and same thing for the update - a `serializer.save()` is called.
Assuming you're using a straightforward [`ModelSerializer`](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/serializers.py#L961-L963), this is what gets called on a `serializer.save()` that does the creation of an object:

```
instance = ModelClass._default_manager.create(**validated_data)
```

So it will use the `_default_manager` of your model, which, [according to the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/db/managers/#default-managers-1), will be the first manager declared on the class - so in theory it should be your custom manager.

Btw, I strongly recommend going through DRF's code whenever you find yourself in situations like these. The code is really straightforward and accessible. There are websites like [`Classy Django REST Framework`](https://www.cdrf.co/) that can make it even easier to navigate around the code.

Comment: Thanks, I was looking around ModelViewSet and not the ModelSerializer to see how create was being handled.